# Combine two different field values when all the others are repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine two cells when the other values in the select are repeated. The field im trying to combine and that will never be the same is the last one in the select.

`SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,table2.name
   FROM table1 
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id 
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.field8 = table2.id 
  WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT table1_id FROM table2_table1 WHERE field8 IN (SELECT field8 FROM table3 WHERE field9 IN (1234))) 
    AND table1.disabled = 0 
    AND table2.id IN (SELECT field8 FROM table3 WHERE field9 IN (1234))`

So basically when fields 1-6 are the same and there are multiple values of the last field show only one row for the record and the last field with the two varchar values combined.

Current output is like this:

Store name 1    1 main street       Portland    OR  97216   ROUTE-AB

Store name 1    1 main street       Portland    OR  97216   ROUTE-BC

I want this:

Store name 1    1 main street       Portland    OR  97216   ROUTE-AB,ROUTE-BC

NOTE:Some of the logic in the inner join might be off as I am working a live database and just tried to replace the names with generic ones.

Comment: Can you please share one example and expected output

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected results.  and...one row from which table.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server!!!  Which one is this????

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???  Table structure???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what data base server my sql or sql server?

Comment: First time asking on this website sorry. I have added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,max(table2.name)+' '+ case when max(table2.name)=min(table2.name) then '' else min(table2.name) end name

from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.field8 = table2.id 

where table1.id in (select table1_id from table2_table1 where field8 in (select field8 from table3 where field9 in (1234))) and table1.disabled=0 and table2.id in (select field8 from table3 where field9 in (1234))
group by field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6
```

Comment: That only gives me the first value of table2.name. I need one row where the values for that are combined.